# Which of the following rings are fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra

there is this Algebra Question i can't figure out:
"Which of the following Rings are fields?:"

- $Z[x]/(3,x^2 + x + 1)$
- $Z[x]/(2,x^2 + x + 1)$

I know that a quotient ring is a field if and only if the ideal is maximal. Also, when i have some principal ideal, say $(x)$ i can just define a homomorphism s.t. $(x)$ is the kernel and then use the first isomorphism theorem. But here defining a suitable homomorphism or proving that the ideal is maximal does not seem so easy, any tips?

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible (and primitive) over $GF(2)$, while the polynomial $x^2+x+1$ is reducible over $GF(3)$, since $x-1$ is a factor mod 3.

Comment: Indeed, over $GF(3)$, one sees that $x^2+x+1=(x-1)^2$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* The question reduces to deciding whether $x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible mod $2$ and $3$. Since the degree is $2$, it suffices to decide  whether it has a root.

Comment: Thanks, I think i figured it out.